# R for loop problems

Tags: r, loops

I have a code similar to this. I have placed it below

```
a<-rnorm(3)
b<-rnorm(10)
c<-array(NA,dim=c(30,1))
for(i in 1:length(a)){
for(j in 1:length(b)){
 c[j]<-a[i]-b[j]
 }
 }
```

The problem: c should be creating 30 values instead of 10. Since a has 3 values and b has 10. each one of a's values were supposed to be subtracting from b thus creating a new with (30,1). 
What should I do?

Comment: `c` is defined with the index `j`, wich goes from 1 to 10 (the `length(b)`. So, this way you will obtain a vector of length 10 not 30

Answer (score 2):

Use the appropriate index into the `c` array:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
    for (j in 1:length(b)) {
        c[(i-1)*length(b) + j] <- a[i]-b[j]
    }
}
```

The index `(i-1)*length(b) + j` will begin at 1 (where the `length(b)` term disappears).  With each iteration of the outer loop in `i` we offset into the `c` array by `length(b)` times the number of outer iterations already completed.

There is probably a better, more vectorized, way of doing this in R.  But from a programming point of view, it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the modulo operator `%%` to get all combinations but the order will be different:

```
for(i in 1:length(c)) {
    c[i] <- a[i %% na + 1L] - b[i %% nb + 1L]
}
```

Or something vectorised:

```
rep(a, 10) - rep(b, 3)
```

But maybe the most tractable solutions is using expand grid to first get all combinations:

```
combins <- expand.grid(a, b)
combins[[1]] - combins[[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for()` loop, you could also use `sapply()`:

```
m <- sapply(a, function(x) x-b)
```

will return a matrix:

```
> m
             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] -0.51424921 -0.60356757 -0.7822274
 [2,]  0.03871073 -0.05060763 -0.2292674
 [3,]  1.21963235  1.13031399  0.9516542
 [4,]  1.27048573  1.18116737  1.0025076
 [5,] -0.37353476 -0.46285312 -0.6415129
 [6,] -1.01243929 -1.10175765 -1.2804174
 [7,]  0.94637733  0.85705897  0.6783992
 [8,] -0.74198691 -0.83130528 -1.0099651
 [9,]  1.06881319  0.97949482  0.8008350
[10,]  1.61434836  1.52502999  1.3463702
```

which you could convert into a one dimensional array with `as.vector()`:

```
> as.vector(m)
 [1] -0.51424921  0.03871073  1.21963235  1.27048573 -0.37353476 -1.01243929  0.94637733 -0.74198691  1.06881319  1.61434836
[11] -0.60356757 -0.05060763  1.13031399  1.18116737 -0.46285312 -1.10175765  0.85705897 -0.83130528  0.97949482  1.52502999
[21] -0.78222735 -0.22926741  0.95165421  1.00250759 -0.64151290 -1.28041743  0.67839919 -1.00996506  0.80083504  1.34637021
```